# Django default value

Tags: django, field, default, models

If I create a field as typed below, will the default value be saved to the object, when the field on the form leaved blank?

```
field_name = models.FloatField(default=100.0, blank=True)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About default for model field :

> The default value is used when new model instances are created and a
>   value isn’t provided for the field. When the field is a primary key,
>   the default is also used when the field is set to None.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#default